# Why does getElementsByClassName work like this?

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, I am really awful at javascript, I am just trying to prepare for my exam the day after tomorrow. Why does this code snippet:

```
var colection=document.getElementsByClassName("old");
for(var i=0; i<colection.length;i++)
colection[i].className="new";
```

Don't work?

Also, why does this:

```
var colection=document.querySelectorAll(".old");
for(var i=0; i<colection.length;i++)
colection[i].className="nou";
```

or this:

```
var vector=[];
var colectie=document.getElementsByClassName("vechi");
for(var i=0;i<colectie.length;i++)
vector[i]=colectie[i];
for(var i=0;i<vector.length;i++)
vector[i].className="nou";
```

Work fine? Our teacher just told us the first one is not correct, but didn't tell us exactly why.

Also, if the first one does not work, why does this:

```
<script>
window.onload=function()
{
var
list=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
alert("There are"+list.length+" paragraphs");
for(var p of list)
{p.style.color="red";}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Colectie</h1>
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
<div>This is a div</div>
</body>
```

work?

I really can not figure out the differences... Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a *live* HTMLCollection meaning it will automatically update itself. So by changing an elements className it gets removed from the list, reducing the length making it skip elements.

```
var colection=document.getElementsByClassName("old");
for(var i=0; i<colection.length;i++)
colection[i].className="new";
```

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is more like a snapshot at the moment of execution. It does not update itself. This means the length doesn't get affected and it can change every elements className.

```
var colection=document.querySelectorAll(".old");
for(var i=0; i<colection.length;i++)
colection[i].className="nou";
```

This example turns your *live* HTMLCollection into an array. Removing the problem of the length changing, therefore skipping elements. They still get removed from the `colectie` but since your looping over the `vector` it doesn't effect the output.

```
var vector=[];
var colectie=document.getElementsByClassName("vechi");
for(var i=0;i<colectie.length;i++)
vector[i]=colectie[i];
for(var i=0;i<vector.length;i++)
vector[i].className="nou";
```

Eventhough [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) also returns a *live* HTMLCollection. In this loop your not changing the tag so the length of the collection will also not change, giving you the output you expect.

```
var list=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
alert("There are"+list.length+" paragraphs");
for(var p of list) {
  p.style.color="red";
}
```